# How to fix npm ERR! Cannot find module './src/table' when running npx create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, npx

On Windows 10, I am getting this error: ***npm ERR! Cannot find module './src/table'*** when trying to start a new project with
npx create-react-app my-app. I searched around but really couldn't find anything about this module './src/table'

Here is the log:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app


Creating a new React app in D:\reandomDirectory.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './src/table'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cli-table3\index.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-audit-report\reporters\detail.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-audit-report\index.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\audit.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-24T01_01_52_667Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\reandomDirectory
Done.
```

I have version 3.4.1 globally installed and even if I try to uninstall it I get the same error.
Also, the directory where I am trying to start the project is completely empty.

Any idea of how I could fix this?

Comment: `npx` always using the latest version. Maybe it's a problem with the newest version (the latest version in npm site is 4.0.3), you can try an older one e.g. `npx create-react-app@4.0.3 my-project`